# How many times has SpaceX reused Falcon 9 first stage until 20th May 2022?

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9, reuse, first-stage

How many times has SpaceX reused Falcon 9 first stage until now?
Not about the possibility. I want to know the current progress with the Falcon 9 first stage.

Comment: That can be easily looked up

Comment: Just go to spacex.com and they will have the current numbers on their website

Comment: Do you want to know how many times a single booster has been reused, or how many overall landings/reflights have taken place?  In any event, this seems like a question that doesn't really belong in a permanent archive because the number will change with every flight.  Perhaps add the specific stat required to the question, and make it explicitly as of a certain date. For example, "How many times has a single Falcon Nine booster been reused as of May 20, 2022?"

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia 13 Falcon 9 Full Thrust and Falcon 9 Block 4 boosters were reused. The remaining 83 are Falcon Block 5 boosters. So, a total of 96 boosters have been recovered as of May 20, 2022. The newest count is always said after each successful landing.